# jq: error Cannot iterate over null (null)

Tags: jq

I have been working with an API call to structure it in JSON format so I might later push it into a database. Then code looks like this:

```
getPage() {
curl --fail -X GET 'https://api.app.com/v1/test?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 123abc456pickupsticks789' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'  
}

getPage \
| jq -c '.items | .[] | {landing_id: .landing_id, submitted_at: .submitted_at, answers: .answers, email: .hidden.email}' \
  > testpush.json
```

When I run it though, it produces this error: jq: error (at :0): Cannot iterate over null (null)

I've looked at solutions such as this one, or this one from this site, and this response.

The common solution seemed to be using a ? in front of [] and I tried it in the jq line towards the bottom, but it still does not work. It just produces an empty json file.

Am I misreading the takeaway from those other answers and not putting my ? in the right place?>

Comment: "Solutions such as this one"  ??  I think you've forgotten some links. Also could we see the response from that curl command?

Answer (score 0):

That means your field `.items` doesn't exist or is null if interpreting the output of your curl as a JSON.

As a side note, the shorter version of your query:

`.items[] | {landing_id, submitted_at, answers, email: .hidden.email}`